# Why does double quotes affect the printing of these echo statements in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, echo, ps

I am capturing output from `ps aux`:

```
current_processes=`ps aux | grep "tempdir" | tail -3`
```

and when I echo it, it looks like this

```
echo $current_processes
19984 10089 17784
```

and when I `echo` plus double quote it, it looks like this:

```
echo "$current_processes"
19984 
10089
17784
```

Why does it put these on new lines when I use double quotes but not in the absence of double quotes?

Answer (score 4):

The effect comes from the shell. Without double quotes the shell replaces newlines, tabs and spaces with spaces. You can avoid this substitution with double quotes. See the section `Word Splitting` in the man page of `bash(1)` for more details:

> **Word Splitting**
>
> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command  substitution,  and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
>   double quotes for word splitting.
>
> The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and  splits  the
>          results of the other expansions into words on these characters.  If IFS
>          is unset, or its value is exactly ,  the  default,
>          then  any  sequence  of IFS characters serves to delimit words.  If IFS
>          has a value other than the default, then sequences  of  the  whitespace
>          characters  space  and  tab are ignored at the beginning and end of the
>          word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value  of  IFS  (an
>          IFS whitespace character).  Any character in IFS that is not IFS white-
>          space, along with any adjacent IFS whitespace  characters,  delimits  a
>          field.   A  sequence  of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a
>          delimiter.  If the value of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.

You can see the content of `IFS` with `echo "$IFS" | xxd`. It will show you

```
00000000: 2009 0a0a                                 ...
```

which means space (0x20), tab (0x09) and newline (0x0a). The second 0x0a comes from the echo command.

You can avoid this substitution by setting `IFS` to the empty string:

```
IFS=""
echo "$current_processes"
19984 
10089
17784
```

But I wouldn't recommend this.